# Is there a good way to email the members of multiple SharePoint groups?

Tags: email, groups, outlook

I have a project site and I have split members of the project site into multiple SharePoint groups for security purposes. I would like to be able to send an email to all the members of several groups. I haven't seen anything that describes this exact use case.

- I can't use AD groups because the membership is too fluid for our in house process.
- I can mimic them in Outlook but that seems counterproductive and they will soon get out of sync.
- I can go each group, select email group and then merge all the recipients into one email. It's less counter productive but seems like a hack..
- Ideally I would like to be able to select the groups I want to email from Outlook

I'm open to any suggestions or third party products.

Thanks

Comment: Is it the same groups everytime?

Comment: No it's not. I do different combinations of groups depending on the email.

Comment: Let me ask you something, why not AD groups? It would solve this issue...

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately adding somebody to an AD group is not a very nimble process right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a SharePoint Designer workflow from a private list that you create, with:

- Incoming email enabled
- Set up the security for Read-Only, other than yourself
- The body of the email will be the body of the email in the workflow
- Specify the SharePoint groups in the List Workflow Action of "Send Email"
- Set the workflow to fire when a new item is created.

Everytime you want to email the users, send an email to this List with the message you want to send.

Comment: Up vote because this is a solution but I would like to see if there are any alternatives.

Comment: I think another solution could be to create an outlook addin that would connect to Sharepoint sites and grab the possible SharePoint groups to add them in Outlook...